# How to prevent a series of tikz nodes from overlapping?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I have the following MWE for the `note` command I'm working on.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper,marginparwidth=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand\note[2][0pt]{
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline=-1ex] \coordinate (e);
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \path let \p1 = (e), \p2 = (current page marginpar area.west) in node[yshift=-#1,text width=\marginparwidth,align=left,anchor=north west,inner ysep=0pt,inner xsep=0pt,font=\normalfont\tiny\color{red}] at (\x2,\y1) {#2};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\usepackage{everypage}
\AddEverypageHook{
    \tikz[remember picture,overlay] {\draw [blue] (current page text area.south west) rectangle (current page text area.north east);}
    \tikz[remember picture,overlay] {\draw [green] (current page marginpar area.south west) rectangle (current page marginpar area.north east);}
}
\begin{document}
\section{\note{Note A}A Test Section}
Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
Donec \note{Note B - pretty long one} vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus
et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra
metus rhoncus sem. \note{Note C} Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla \note{Note D} ultrices. Phasellus
eu tellus sit \note{Note E} amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium
quis, viverra ac, nunc.tus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis.
\end{document}
```

I would like the `Note E` to be shifted below `Note D`. Currently I could do that manually by precising `yshift`, but I think it can be easily done without the need of hand-tuning.

I could think of an algorithm

1. Save bottom of the note position
2. When placing next note check if top position is less than previous bottom
3. Calculate required `yshift`

However as a beginner I have no idea how to implement that behavior in `tikz`. Any help appreciated `:)`

**Update**

There is also a secondary question here - if I try to remove the optional argument (just to make it `\newcommand\note[1]{`) I end up with the error

```
! Use of \use@tikzlibrary doesn't match its definition.
\pgfutil@ifnextchar ...1\def \pgfutil@reserved@a { #2}\def \pgfutil@reserved@...
l.20 \section{\note{Note A}A Test Section}
```

Of course I remember about changing references. What's going on?

**Test code**

To show what happens with `align` and `tabu`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper,marginparwidth=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\tikzset{
  marginpar node/.style={
    text width=\marginparwidth,
    align=left,
    inner sep=+0pt,
    font=\normalfont\tiny,
    text=red}}
\makeatletter
\def\tikz@marginpar@node@page{-1}%
\protected\def\note#1{%
  \tikzpicture[remember picture, overlay]
    \pgfutil@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@tikz@marginpar@node}{%
      \coordinate (@tikz@marginpar@node@c)at (0pt, 1ex-|current page marginpar area.west);
    }{%
      \ifnum\tikz@marginpar@node@page=\c@page\relax
        \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{tikz@marginpar@node}{south west}}
                     {\pgfpoint{+0pt}{+1ex}}
        \ifdim\pgf@y<-3pt\relax
          \coordinate (@tikz@marginpar@node@c)
            at (0pt,1ex-|current page marginpar area.west);
        \else
          \coordinate (@tikz@marginpar@node@c)
            at ([yshift=-3pt]tikz@marginpar@node.south west);
        \fi
      \else
        \coordinate (@tikz@marginpar@node@c)
            at (0pt,1ex-|current page marginpar area.west);
      \fi
    }
    \node [marginpar node/.try, anchor=north west, alias=tikz@marginpar@node]
            at (@tikz@marginpar@node@c) {\setlength\baselineskip{0pt}#1};
    \xdef\tikz@marginpar@node@page{\the\c@page}%
  \endtikzpicture}
\makeatother
\usepackage{everypage}
\AddEverypageHook{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]{
    \draw[blue]  (current page text area.south west) rectangle
                    (current page text area.north east);
    \draw[green] (current page marginpar area.south west) rectangle
                    (current page marginpar area.north east);}%
}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhf[HL]{\def\note##1{}\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\thesection\ #1}{}}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
{\def\note#1{}\tableofcontents}

\section{\note{Note A}A Test Section}
Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
Donec \note{Note B - pretty long one} vehicula augue eu neque.
Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus
et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra
metus rhoncus sem. \note{Note C} Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla
\note{Note D} ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit \note{Note E} amet tortor
gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac,
nunc.tus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis.

\newpage
\section{\note{Note A}A Test Section}
Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
Donec \note{Note B - pretty long one} vehicula augue eu neque.
Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus
et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra
metus rhoncus sem. \note{Note C} Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla
\note{Note D} ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit \note{Note E} amet tortor
gravida placerat. \note{Note F} Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, 
viverra ac, nunc.tus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis.

\newpage
Morbi dolor\note{More testing} nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. 
Cur-abitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. 
\begin{center}
Duis nibh mi, congue \note{center}
eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim
rutrum.
\end{center}
\begin{displaymath}
a+b+c =\note{display math} d+e+f
\end{displaymath}
Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi
auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, \note{Test} lobortis vitae, 
ultricies et, tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum, erat ligula 
aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis.
\begin{multicols}{2}
Erat ligula aliquet magna,
vitae ornare odio metus a mi. Morbi nisl \note{Something is wrong here} mollis. 
Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum. Suspendisse
ut massa. Cras nec ante. Pellentesque a nulla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et
magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam tincidunt urna. 
Nulla ullamcorper vestibulum turpis. Nulla ullamcorper 
$f(x)=\note{This requires special attention}f(-x)$ vestibulum turpis. 
Pellentesque cursus luctus mauris.
\end{multicols}

Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi
auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, 
ultricies et, tellus.

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Strop&Spag&H&Symbol&Nazwa\\\hline
0&4.05&\note{Table comment?}4.05&$Ps$&Piasek sredni\\\hline
4.05&5.30&1.25&$T$&Torf\\\hline
5.30&7.60&2.30&$Gz$&Glina zwiezla\\\hline
7.60&$\infty$&$\infty$&$P \pi$&Piasek pylasty\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\newpage
Morbi dolor\note{More testing} nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. 
Cur-abitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. 
\begin{center}
Duis nibh mi, congue \note{center}
eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim
rutrum.
\end{center}
\begin{align}
a+b+c &= d+e+f \\
&\note{Rly equal?}= g +h \\
&= i.
\end{align}
Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi
auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, \note{Test} 
lobortis vitae, ultricies et,
tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum, erat ligula aliquet magna,
vitae ornare odio metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis.
\begin{multicols}{2}
Erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio 
metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl \note{Something is wrong here} mollis. 
Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum. Suspendisse
ut massa. Cras nec ante. Pellentesque a nulla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et
magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam tincidunt urna. 
Nulla ullamcorper vestibulum turpis. Nulla ullamcorper 
$f(x)=\note{This requires special attention}f(-x)$ vestibulum turpis. 
Pellentesque cursus luctus mauris.
\end{multicols}

Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi
auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, 
ultricies et, tellus.

\begin{center}
\begin{tabu}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Strop&Spag&H&Symbol&Nazwa\\\hline
0&4.05&\note{Table comment?}4.05&$Ps$&Piasek sredni\\\hline
4.05&5.30&1.25&$T$&Torf\\\hline
5.30&7.60&2.30&$Gz$&Glina zwiezla\\\hline
7.60&$\infty$&$\infty$&$P \pi$&Piasek pylasty\\\hline
\end{tabu}
\end{center}

\newpage
Restart?\note{restart}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Secondary question: You need to use `\protect\note` in the `\section` or `\protected\def\note#1{` instead of `\newcommand\node[1]`. See [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4736)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel thanks for the comment, pretty useful and in fact did the trick. Anyway I am still working on the first part of my question, could you enlighten me please how to use `\ifthenelse` to compare two `tikz` `\coordinate`'s? Or simply return greater y of two.

Comment: See my answer, but please be aware that if you use `\tableofcontents` this will also have the notes, you should do something along the lines of `{\def\note#1{}\tableofcontents}` then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `calc`-less solution.

First we check whether a node `tikz@marginpar@node` exists. If some exist we calculate the difference between `(tikz@marginpar@node.south west)` and `(0pt, 1ex)` (unless the previous note was on a different page). If the *y* part less than 0, `(0pt, 1ex)` is too high and thus the previous `tikz@marginpar@node` is used to position the new node.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper,marginparwidth=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\tikzset{
  marginpar node/.style={
    text width=\marginparwidth,
    align=left,
    inner sep=+0pt,
    font=\normalfont\tiny,
    text=red}}
\makeatletter
\def\tikz@marginpar@node@page{-1}%
\protected\def\note#1{%
  \tikzpicture[remember picture, overlay]
    \pgfutil@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@tikz@marginpar@node}{%
      \coordinate (@tikz@marginpar@node@c)at (0pt, 1ex-|current page marginpar area.west);
    }{%
      \ifnum\tikz@marginpar@node@page=\c@page\relax
        \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{tikz@marginpar@node}{south west}}
                     {\pgfpoint{+0pt}{+1ex}}
        \ifdim\pgf@y<0pt\relax
          \coordinate (@tikz@marginpar@node@c)
                                          at (0pt,1ex-|current page marginpar area.west);
        \else
          \coordinate (@tikz@marginpar@node@c)
                                      at ([yshift=-.75ex]tikz@marginpar@node.south west);
        \fi
      \else
        \coordinate (@tikz@marginpar@node@c)
                                          at (0pt,1ex-|current page marginpar area.west);
      \fi
    }
    \node [marginpar node/.try, anchor=north west, alias=tikz@marginpar@node]
                                                 at (@tikz@marginpar@node@c) {#1};
    \xdef\tikz@marginpar@node@page{\the\c@page}%
  \endtikzpicture}
\makeatother
\usepackage{everypage}
\AddEverypageHook{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]{
    \draw[blue]  (current page text area.south west)      rectangle
                                                     (current page text area.north east);
    \draw[green] (current page marginpar area.south west) rectangle
                                             (current page marginpar area.north east);}%
}
\begin{document}
{\def\note#1{}\tableofcontents}

\section{\note{Note A}A Test Section}
Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
Donec \note{Note B - pretty long one} vehicula augue eu neque.
Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus
et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra
metus rhoncus sem. \note{Note C} Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla
\note{Note D} ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit \note{Note E} amet tortor
gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac,
nunc.tus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis.

\newpage
\section{\note{Note A}A Test Section}
Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
Donec \note{Note B - pretty long one} vehicula augue eu neque.
Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus
et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra
metus rhoncus sem. \note{Note C} Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla
\note{Note D} ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit \note{Note E} amet tortor
gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac,
nunc.tus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis.
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however could you expain me a few things? **1.** `...(0pt, 1ex-|current page margin...` whats does that `1ex-|` do? **2.** If in `{\pgfpoint{+0pt}{+1ex}}` 1ex is a minimal allowed distance between notes why do you use `[yshift=-.75ex]` instead of `[yshift=-1ex]`? **3.** `\tableofcontents` is fine now, but what about `\sectionmark` - section title in the header (using `fancyhdr`)? **4.** How could one modify `\baselineskip` in the note content?

Comment: @Paul **1.** The `-|` (as well as the `|-`) is the explicit version of the `perpendicular cs:` and denotes the coordinate horizontal through `0pt, 1ex` and vertical through `current page margin area.west`, i.e. the same coordinate that you used `let … in` for. **2.** No, `\pgfpoint{0pt}{1ex}` is the PGF version of `(0pt, 1ex)`. The `1ex` are the same `1ex` you use to denote the coordinate `(e)` which vertical part you use to place the node (at its `north west` anchor). We check if the new `north west` anchor would be higher then the `south west` anchor of the previous node. *cont.*

Comment: The `.75ex` is simply the distance between the old `south west` and the new `north west` anchor, i.e. the vertical distance between the nodes if the new one would overlap the previous one. **3.** No idea at the moment. Though `\label` works the same way (you can use it in `\section`s and `\caption`s without a problem), maybe there is a related Q on TeX.sx. **4.** As always in LaTeX: Either with `\fontsize` or `\setlength\baselineskip`.

Comment: **1.** I understand that is tikz way to get the coordinate `(marginpar.X, here.Y + 1ex)` **2.** Then we have to test diff against `.75ex`, because it might happen that two notes do not  overlap, but are still too close [example](http://i.imgur.com/Hx8imDM.png), assuming `.75ex=3pt` `\ifdim\pgf@y<-3pt\relax` fixes the issue. I assumed 3pt because I guess .75ex won't work out of the node scope. **3.** I adapted your solution for `\tableofcontents`: `\fancyhf[HL]{\def\note##1{}\leftmark}` and it's fine **4.** I want to change spacing between lines `{\setlength\baselineskip{0pt}#1}` doesn't work.

Comment: Moreover putting `\note{...}` into more elaborate environments  like `align` (`amsmath`) or `tabu` (table) results in note dissappearing altogether with each further on the page. What is even more weird `displaymath` and `tabular` works fine. Original code works in all cases. I edited question to give an example of what I am talking about.